# What's the appropriate place to add additional validity checks for transactions?

Tags: transaction-data

What's the appropriate place to add additional validity checks for transactions? (check_tx_inputs?, does every tx pass through this, including during reorgs and such?)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place, yes. This is called before a (non coinbase) transaction is accepted, except when running `monero-blockchain-import` with verifiction turned off (which you should not do unless you exported the file yourself). It will be called also when reorgs happen.